# Why is there an ever-growing uvcydnctrl-udev.log file filling up my harddisk?

Tags: 16.04

I tried to hibernate my system using

```
pm-hibernate
```

and it did hibernate. But on booting up the system, it crashed. 
I had to hard reboot my system. Next thing I know is my harddisk is full due to `uvcydnctrl-udev.log`.

Why is there an ever-growing uvcydnctrl-udev.log file filling up my harddisk? Also, can I do something to stop this, or – at least – to keep the file from wasting all my diskspace?

Comment: again the same file was created.... somebody please enlighten me on this... out of nowhere my harddisk starts blinking and almost 20GB of this log file is created at /var/log.... what is this ??? how do i stop it? .. i have already deleted two last created using 'sudo rm'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libwebcam/+bug/811604) in `libwebcam` and is *not* dangerous. You will have to run `sudo rm /var/log/uvcdynctrl-udev.log` every once in a while, possibly through a shell script and a cron job. This the best thing you can do, until the bug is fixed.

## The script

```
#!/bin/bash
PW = "yourpassword"

echo $PW | sudo -S rm /var/log/uvcdynctrl-udev.log
```

Save the script as `rmlog.sh`, make it executable with `chmod +x rmlog.sh`.

## The cron job

Move `rmlog.sh` to `/etc/cron.hourly/` with

```
sudo mv rmlog.sh /etc/cron.hourly/
```

Comment: DAMN the BUG was reported on 2011....."every once in a while".. huh.. i am thinking of writing a shell script to autorun every 1 hour to check and delete  WHATEVER this is....

Comment: *Please* don't write scripts like that one. Never put your password in a plain text file like that! Just use root's crontab instead (`sudo crontab -e`). But even if you use `/etc/cron.hourly`, that will run as root so there's no need for `sudo` so no need to use a password in the script.